# Symfony override repository of another bundle does not override it

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I want to override entity and repository of another bundle

So

I want to override

```
src/MyBundle/Entity/Product
src/MyBundle/Entity/ProductRepository
```

So i have created another bundle AppBundle

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/Product extends src/MyBundle/Entity/Product
src/AppBundle/Entity/ProductRepository extends src/MyBundle/Entity/ProductRepository
```

So in AppBundle i want to add some properties and also want to write custom query in ProductRepository.

So

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'MyBundle';
    }
}

In my AppBundle entity i have specify repository of src/AppBundle/Entity/ProductRepository
```

How can i do that?

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product extends Base
{
}
```

$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product') gives repository of

```
MyBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
```

Comment: Do you want to override or extends ? It is not the same thing

Comment: Right - this question is unclear.  What are you specifically trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JasonRoman i have edited question.